# MySQL FK field does not show up for InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I have a weird situation. I recently realigned my MySQL tables changing the table names and field names and capitalizing them.  However, when I try to reassign the FK constraints, the FK field does not show up in the Relation View. Only the Internal Relation shows up. I double checked and they are still InnoDB.

I also ran a query for listing FK from Info-schema and it returned an empty set.  That confirms no FK defined.

Any idea what could be the issue? Is capitalizing the table names an issue?

[image: Table Type InnoDB with capitalized table names]

[image: All I see is this]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that capitalizing the table names is the problem. Once I changed the table name to small letters, I could see those fields.  I really wonder why.  Is there any way to make it work with capitalized table names?

[image: Fields show after name change]

**EDIT:** The issue was in the MySQL directive (in the ini file) which I had set as `lower_case_table_names = 2`. I changed this to `lower_case_table_names = 0` and it works fine now with capitalized names.

Comment: Tbh, you shouldn't capitalize any schema attributes (table names, column names), it's unnecessary and will only lead to confusion down the road.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I think it is a personal preference and for me, it looks cleaner this way since underscores annoy me. The issue was with the ini directive which I fixed now.

Comment: Understood, just speaking from experience. I have NEVER seen an upper case, or even camel cased schema attribute in all the years I have been developing, the universal standard is lowercase with underscore separators. If, 6 months from now, you regret your choice, you owe me a beer.

Comment: Sure. But can you explain what problems you forsee later?  Just because no one used it that way does not mean we shouldn't. NoSQL felt absurd when it was first proposed amidst robust RBDMS systems but it set a precedence for Big data. If you can point some critical issues that one might face by using capitalized names, I would like to change it.

Comment: Well for one thing, it's much easier to discern between schema attributes and sql syntax if your schema attributes are lowercase.